# Machine learning with a variable-sized real vector of inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I have a collection of objects with properties that I measure. For each object, I obtain a vector of real numbers describing that object. The vector is always incomplete: there's usually numbers missing from the beginning or end of what would be the complete vector, and sometimes there is information missing in the middle. Hence, each object results in a vector of a different length. I also measure, say, the mass of each object, and I now want to relate the vector of things I've measured to the mass.

It's common in my field (astrophysics) to extract features from this vector of real numbers, e.g. take an average or some linear combinations of the values; and then use those extracted features to infer the mass (or whatever) using for example neural networks. It was recently shown, however, that a very complex combination of the elements of the vector result in a much better model of the mass.

There are still residuals in this model, however, even when working on simulated data. Presumably then there is a better way out there to manipulate these variable-length vectors in order to get a better model.

I am wondering if it is possible to do machine learning with real-valued input vectors of all different lengths. I know for text mining there are things like the bag-of-words approach, but it is unclear how such a method would work on real-valued vectors. I know recurrent neural networks work on sentences of variable length, but I'm not sure they work for real-valued vectors. I have also considered imputing the missing data; however, sometimes it is missing for physical reasons, i.e. a value in such-and-such place cannot exist, and so imputing it would violate the physicality of the situation.

Is there any research in this area?

Comment: Do I take it correctly that you don't know *which* feature it is that is at position X in your feature vector? If you know, you are not dealing with feature vectors of different length in the classical sense, but likely have lots of unknown ("NA") information in your feature vector. If you don't know: are your features ordered (similar to a time series measurements) or could you e.g. "shuffle" them?

Comment: @geekoverdose interesting questions! I am measuring a physical thing, where sometimes the information is just plain missing ("NA") but other times the information is nonphysical---it can't exist, just like a person who is standing has no lap---so I am not sure if this is "NA" material. The information can be considered as ordered, i.e. it is possible to label them in a sequence, but it is not exactly necessary to do so, and it is occasionally difficult to do the labeling. I would be happy to hear about both sequential or non-sequential solutions to this problem.

Comment: Then I would possibly consider the "missing property" to be information itself (e.g. binary/dummy variables). You could use this information in your prediction tasks straight with certain model types, but you could also employ it in e.g. tree-like models, where it could be used do automatically form more homogeneous groups, for which e.g. other models could to the prediction of the target variable.

Answer (score 1):

Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs) are capable of taking a variable-sized input vector of length n and producing a variable sized output vector of length m.

There are many ways to make RNNs work. The most common cell types are called Long short-term memory (LSTM) and Gated Recurrent Unit (GRU).

You might want to read:

- [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/): Nice to get an idea what RNNs are capable of, especially character predictors. It is easy to read, but not exactly what you're searching.
- [Understanding LSTM Networks](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/): More technical; very well written
- Sepp Hochreiter, Jurgen Schmidhuber: [LONG SHORT-TERM MEMORY](http://deeplearning.cs.cmu.edu/pdfs/Hochreiter97_lstm.pdf)
- [RNNs in TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/recurrent/index.html)

However, training RNNs takes a lot of training data. You might be better off with computing a fixed-size feature vector from it. But you never know when you don't try it ;-)

Comment: I can generate arbitrary amounts of training data (I'm working from simulations!) so I will definitely give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: I remain a bit confused though. I've read the first two sites you linked and it seems they're mainly used for generating samples from the model they've learned. Can these architectures also be used for the traditional regression/classification type tasks that regular neural networks are trained for?

Comment: Yes, RNNs can be used for sequence labeling. Usually it is used when you have multiple classes in one sequence and you don't know where to split, but I am pretty sure having only a single class for a sequence should be possible to. However, I don't know a good paper for this right now.

Comment: I have another question. If I know that the real data I will test the RNN on has missing values, should I simulate this situation and add gaps to the training data? My training data will be vectors of length ~150 (all the same unit), but the real data that I want to use it on has only 25 or so of these values.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron I never had to deal with missing values. However, I think it usually is a good idea to make the training data as similar as possible to the test data.